# Capitalizar palabras

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código que hace que todas las letras se hagan minúsculas si el usuario tiene las mayúsculas activadas

```
    function mayusculas(aqui){ 
             var pepe="KarlanKas"; 
    palabras=aqui.value.split(" "); 
    for(a=0;a<palabras.length;a++){ 
        letra=palabras[a].charAt(0); 
        palabras[a] = letra + palabras[a].substring(1 , palabras[a].length).toLowerCase(); 

    } 
    texto=""; 
    for(a=0;a<palabras.length;a++){ 
        if(a>0){texto+=" ";} 
        texto+=palabras[a]; 
    } 
    aqui.value=texto; 
}
```

El codigo funciona, si escribo HOLA, El resultado es: Hola
Pero si escribo: hola, el resultado es: hola

Lo que quiero hacer es que la primera letra siempre sea mayuscula, lo de las minisculas ya esta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo necesitas poner manualmente la letra a mayuscula y establecer que sea sólo para la primera palabra (primer elemento)

```
if(a == 0)
    letra=palabras[a].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Gracias xd, apenas empiezo en js

Comment: @Jenio158 si la respuesta ayudó en tu solución considera marcarla como aceptada para que sirva de apoyo a otros desarrolladores, saludos

Comment: Alejandro, aun le falta, el codigo convierte la primera palabra a mayuscula de todo, ej: Hola Que Haces, solo quiero la primera de todo.

Comment: Deberías haber sido más específico con eso, editaré mi respuesta para que sea más legible

Comment: No me funciona, si presiono espacio se pone una A sola.

Comment: asi lo edite
    function mayusculas(aqui){ 
                 var pepe="KarlanKas"; 
        palabras=aqui.value.split(" "); 
        for(a=0;a<palabras.length;a++){ 
        if(a == 0)
            letra=palabras[a].charAt(0).toUpperCase(); 
            palabras[a] = letra + palabras[a].substring(1 , palabras[a].length).toLowerCase(); 
             
        } 
        texto=""; 
        for(a=0;a<palabras.length;a++){ 
            if(a>0){texto+=" ";} 
            texto+=palabras[a]; 
        } 
        aqui.value=texto; 
    }

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, me falto cerrar una llave

Answer (score 1):

Si sólo te interesa la primera letra en mayúsculas y el resto en minúsculas, entonces otra forma de hacerlo sería convirtiendo esa primer letra a mayúscula y luego, todo el resto a minúscula usando `slice`.

Si el resto de las letras las quieres tal y como están escritas, entonces quitas `.toLowerCase()`.

```js
/*función*/

function capitalizeOnlyFirst(string) 
{
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

/*Hacemos algunas pruebas*/
console.log(capitalizeOnlyFirst('HOLA MUNDO'));
console.log(capitalizeOnlyFirst('HOLA'));
console.log(capitalizeOnlyFirst('hOLA'));
```